# #Mongodb - How to get the size of an array WITHIN an array of objects?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I try to get the length of an array in an array of objects, but I always get 1 no matter how long the array actually is.

**My update query looks like this:**

```
   const list = await personalWordLists.updateOne(
        {"user_id": userID,  "lists.list_id": list_id }, 
        [
            {
                $set: {
                    "lists.last_practiced": last_practiced,
                    "lists.wordCount": { $size: "$lists.word_ids" } 
                }
            }
        ]
    )
```

When I query the length of *lists*, then it works and I get the correct length of the array.

**My document looks like this:**
[image]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I have updated the answer, see if this is what you are looking for...

Answer (score 0):

You have to make use of Aggregation Pipeline support for the update command which will work on MongoDB versions >= 4.2

Use `$map` inside the `$set` pipeline to iterate through elements of the `lists` array and apply the conditions and operations required. In your case merge existing keys with `"wordCount": {"$size": "$$elemword_ids"}` and other keys you want to be changed for the matched element.

```
db.collection.update({
  // Your Match Conditions
  "user_id": userID,
  "lists.list_id": list_id,
},
[
  {
    "$set": {
      "lists": {
        "$map": {
          "input": "$lists",
          "as": "elem",
          "in": {
            "$cond": {
              "if": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$elem.list_id",
                  list_id
                ]
              },
              "then": {
                "$mergeObjects": [
                  "$$elem",
                  {
                    "wordCount": {
                      "$size": "$$elem.word_ids"
                    },
                    "last_practiced": last_practiced
                  },
                ],
              },
              "else": "$$elem",
            },
          },
        }
      },
    },
  },
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! Unfortunately it only work partly. The size value is now equal to the length of the array, but the query breaks the document (as you can see here: https://snipboard.io/3AGHSn.jpg).

Comment: Just to make things clear: I've got an array of list objects. I need to update only one list object by adding word_ids and a date. After that I want to add the number of word_ids in that specific list object.

Comment: I completely misunderstood your question. Apologies for the inconvenience caused. I have updated my answer, let me know if it worked for you